Is probability actually “objective” in quantum mechanics?
Quantum Mechanics is taken to be an example of a field that may show the existence of “objective” probabilities.
For example, there may be a defined, truly objective probability for an atom to decay within a certain timespan.
But the probability of an atom decaying within a certain time span is calculated by observing the percentage of atoms amongst a group of atoms historically that decay within a certain period of time.
Thus, does this not hinge upon the inference that the very next atom must be representative of all past groups of atoms similar to it? If so, in what sense are these probabilities objective?

NOTE: A user has pointed out a similarity to this question in the comments but the accepted answer does not address this question.
The accepted answer states that probabilities are objective under the Copenhagen interpretation of QM. But even in this interpretation, how exactly are probabilities objective, if the way we calculate them is based on historical frequencies? Why does a historical frequency of groups of atoms (which is objective) imply an objective probability for a single atom?

Related: Are there probabilistic facts of the matter about the universe?

From the accepted answer: The Indeterministic View (Objective Probabilities Exist): According to some interpretations of quantum physics, some events are intrinsically probabilistic, which implies that objective probabilities are a basic aspect of reality. The Copenhagen interpretation, for instance, asserts that quantum occurrences have objective probabilities. Source: Heisenberg, W. (1927). "The Physical Principles of the Quantum Theory."

There are six major interpretations of probability, and three of them, frequentist, propensity and best-system, admit objective probabilities. However, for them to have metaphysical import one also has to assume existence of objectively random events that are subject to statistical regularities (for whatever reason). In other words, even "omniscient universe" cannot predict their outcomes before they happen. Indeterministic interpretations of QM postulate such events. Otherwise, probabilities depend on predictor's knowledge.

(Note: I copy-pasted above this comment from Conifold)

@user80226 The accepted answer is part of my question. Even in the Copenhagen interpretation, how exactly are probabilities objective, if the way we calculate them is based on historical frequencies?

@Lowri I have attached a note to the end of this question to show why answers to the linked question don’t address mine

Suppose we consider, instead, the number of protons in its nucleus. Could you not also say of that, "does this not hinge upon the inference that the very next atom must be representative of all past groups of atoms similar to it? If so, in what sense is this number objective?" I believe Hume had something to say along these lines...

There are totally deterministic interpretations of quantum mechanics.

Whether there are objective probabilities is unconnected with whether there is error or uncertainty in our estimation of those probabilities.
You say:

But the probability of an atom decaying within a certain time span is calculated by observing the percentage of atoms amongst a group of atoms historically that decay within a certain period of time.

That does not undermine the existence of objective probabilities. As explained at another Q&A, how one conceives of objective probabilities (their existence and what they mean) "depends on one's stance on determinism and the interpretation of quantum mechanics," not on how we come to estimate them.
That there are objective probabilities flows from one interpretation of the currently posited theory of quantum mechanics. It does not depend on how we observe those playing out in messy interactive environments.

Why does it not undermine it? Why does a historical frequency of groups of atoms (which is objective) imply an objective probability for a single atom?

@Syed I feel you need to be more specific about what you mean by objective here. Do you think there are any objective facts about the future? If so, is the number of atoms that will decay in a given sample over the next hour among those objective facts?

Radioactive decay of atoms is absolutely random.
This means that it is absolutely impossible to predict when a certain atom will decay. There is only the half life time. This is the time after which statiscally half the atoms will have decayed.
What is remarkable, is that atoms don't age. This means that if half the atoms have decayed after a billion year, the atoms that haven't decayed will still be as 'new'. That is, after another billion year, half of those left will have decayed. And so on.
